# How to compare the logged username with DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, code-behind

I'm trying to compare the name of the logged username in XAML. I set it in codebehind in a variable with `"System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name"` and I'm trying to set it as a value in a DataTrigger, but Visual Studio tells me that I can't use `Binding` in a `DataTrigger` Value, only in a `DependencyProperty` or `DependencyObject`.

I've tried one thousand ways but I always get the same error. Any idea?

```
public string usuarioactual;

public Amigos()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    presenter = new PresenterAmigos(this);
    presenter.ObtenerAmistades();
    presenter.ObtenerUsuarioActual();
    usuarioactual = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;

}


<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Recibida.Email}" Value="{Binding usuarioactual}">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Enviada.Email}"/>
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Enviada.Email}" Value="{Binding usuarioactual}">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding Recibida.Email}"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  [BindingConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) that evaluates to `true/false` and use this`true/false` as value condition in `DataTrigger`.

```
public class UserNameToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var username = (string)value;
        if (username == "System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name")
          return true;
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just make your `usuarioactual` variable a `DependencyProperty`

```
public Amigos()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    presenter = new PresenterAmigos(this);
    presenter.ObtenerAmistades();
    presenter.ObtenerUsuarioActual();
    usuarioactual = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
}

public string usuarioactual
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(usuarioactualProperty); }
    set { SetValue(usuarioactualProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for usuarioactual.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty usuarioactualProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("usuarioactual", typeof(string), typeof(Amigos), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
```